# Spring MVC Junit Test ApplicationContext Config

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit

I think I should be using the same application context config files with Junit test! is that correct?

The issue that I have, I can run my spring mvc app without an issue, and I am trying to add a new junit test to test one of the controller and I can't even run the test. obviously the application context files are not the issue, as the app is running perfectly fine. So the question is how can I run a junit test using the existing application context config files? any link or example would be appreciated.

Currently my application context files are located in /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/*-appContext.xml

In my web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/*-appContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

I have no problem to run the app but I can't run the test.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:105)
```

In the testing class;

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mvc-appContext.xml")
public class AppTests {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
```

also I have tried using "*"

```
file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/*-appContext.xml
```

and tried using multiple files

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
        "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mvc-appContext.xml",
        "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mongo-appContext.xml"})
```

and tried using single xml to import others

```
<import resource="file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mvc-appContext.xml"/>
<import resource="file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mongo-appContext.xml"/>
```

but none of them work for junit testing! so where should I put the config files?

It doesn't seem to initialize other beans!

```
     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:105)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'verificationTokenService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.pcd.core.repository.UserRepository com.pcd.core.service.VerificationTokenService.userRep; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.pcd.core.repository.UserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.pcd.core.repository.UserRepository com.pcd.core.service.VerificationTokenService.userRep; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.pcd.core.repository.UserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.pcd.core.repository.UserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 41 more
```

Comment: You have to show us the exact beans that are not loading (post full stack trace) and where they are defined in the contexts you are trying to load. Your configuration seems correct to me.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the post, see is that enough info?

Comment: Now we know that a `UserRepository` bean cannot be found. Let's see where it is defined.

Comment: I use this " <mongo:repositories base-package="com.pcd.core.repository"/>" in one of my *-appContext.xml config file.

Comment: Would be nice to know: was this was ever solved?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I configured my tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextHierarchy({
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = MyAppConfig.class),
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp-controller.xml"),
    @ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/rest-controller.xml")})

public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

     @Before
     public void setUp() {
       this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
     }
```

In my case I had a third listing "MyAppConfig" (annotations). I included, just so you have an example. In your case you can remove `@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyAppConfig.class),`

Edit the above to include you specific files.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I expanded my example to include the setUp(). Can you post your setUp().

Comment: is the same as yours!

Comment: Have you tried running the test through a debugger. Can you verify whether both your WebApplicationContext and MockMvc instances are being initialized? Also, you have extra set of quotation marks in you post ""file:

Comment: it didn't even get to the setup() method.

Comment: Thanks again for the response. How are you running the tests. Is this your only test listing for the project? Are running just this class. How many tests are in the class? Note, you haven't detailed what you are trying to test?

Comment: that is the only test i have! just started to add junit test to my app. I just found out that if I removed this "<context:component-scan base-package="com.test"/>" from the appContext.xml, then it runs the empty test ok. so I guess it is that when it scans the others controllers and can't find the dependency of other beans. so it throws " Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type"

Comment: That is correct. Your tests are separate from your application. You don't configure the test classes as part of your app. Does that close this (answered)?

Comment: nope, what is the point of testing an empty method? I need other dependencies, to test the actual controllers! also its better to have the same config files for both testing and the actual app. otherwise u will keep editing both!

Comment: Thank you for the response. Please edit you post to include the additional details of your question. Are now asking how to implement a specific test? If so, please specify your question.Good Luck:)

Comment: question is still the same. I can run my app without an issue with the applicationContext configuration files but I can't run a test with using the same configuration files!

Comment: I see. So you want to know how to configure your app so that the unit tests are not part of the production build. Is that correct, you currently configured your test suite as part of you application context. You want to know how to remove the tests from a production deployment?

Comment: The issue that I have, I can run my spring mvc app without an issue, and I am trying to add a new junit test to test one of the controller and I can't even run the test! so that mean my application context files have no issue as my app is running perfectly ok! so the question is how can I run a test case using the same configuration files?

Answer (score 0):

Create separate resource folder for testsuit. Set it in classpath.
You can load it like below.

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
```